# Trigger ngSubmit from (blur)

Tags: angular

I have a form in Angular 2, where I'm trying to trigger the form's (ngSubmit) event when one of the fields is blurred, but using the (blur) event to call the function doesn't pass the model elements.

Here is the code:

```
  <form 
    #phoneForm="ngForm"
    (ngSubmit)="addPhone(phoneForm)"
    style="width:100%;">
      <ion-grid>
          <ion-row class="edit-field">
            <ion-col col-auto class="field-icon">
                <ion-icon name="md-remove-circle"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-auto class="field-type">
                <select
                  ngModel 
                  id="phoneType"
                  name="phoneType"
                  #phoneType="ngModel">
                    <option 
                    value="select"
                    ng-selected="true"
                    ng-disabled="true" > -- Select -- </option>
                    <option value="home" >home</option>
                    <option value="mobile" >mobile</option>
                    <option value="business" >business</option>
                    <option value="home fax" >home fax</option>
                    <option value="work fax" >work fax</option>
                    <option value="fax">fax</option>
                  </select>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col class="field-input">
                <input 
                  type="text"
                  name="phoneNumber"
                  name="phoneNumber"
                  id="phoneNumber"
                  ngModel 
                  #phoneNumber="ngModel"
                  placeholder="Phone" 
                  ng-blur="addPhone()">
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
  </form>
```

As a simple test, I have this function in the component:

```
  addPhone(data){
    console.log('Hit add phone', data.value);
  }
```

How do you submit a form on blur?

Comment: Did you try putting `(blur)="addPhone(phoneForm)` on the form element?

Comment: I did, and still get the "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: vincecampanale - This is an Angular app, not AngularJS.